# cumsum for unique value using dplyr mutate

Tags: r, cumsum, dplyr

The dummy dataset is:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6),
  value = c(10,10,20,20,10,30,40,50),
  other = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
)
```

The data was output of `group_by(id)` operation in `dplyr` pipe. Each `id` is associated with at most one value and two different `id` can have same value. I need to find cumulative sum across ids by adding new column:
`cum_col = c(10,10,30,30,40,70,110,160)`
The `cumsum` in `mutate` will find cumulative sum across whole column of values and doesn't pick only one value per group. `summarise` is not useful as there are other columns I need to keep intact.

Is there a way out without using `summarise` and then `join`-ing it backward? Or please point me to link if it has been answered before.

Edit: Just for info the actual data has ~2 million rows and 100 columns.

Comment: Do you need only `dplyr` answer or you are open to other options as well ? Also, a group would always have only one unique `value` ?

Comment: Only `dplyr` as am using pipe to do couple of other mutations and operations in one code block

Comment: Yes, group will always have one unique value

Answer (score 3):

One alternative could be *nest* the data frame by *id* column, calculate the cumulative sum and then *unnest*:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% nest() %>% 
    mutate(cum_col = cumsum(sapply(data, function(dat) dat$value[1]))) %>% 
    unnest() 

# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     id cum_col value other
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1      10    10     1
#2     1      10    10     2
#3     2      30    20     3
#4     2      30    20     4
#5     3      40    10     5
#6     4      70    30     6
#7     5     110    40     7
#8     6     160    50     8
```

---

Compare to `summarize` and `join`:

```
summarise_f <- function(data) data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(val = first(value)) %>%
    mutate(cum_col = cumsum(val)) %>%
    select(-val) %>%
    inner_join(data, by="id")

nest_f <- function(data) data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% nest() %>% 
    mutate(cum_col = cumsum(sapply(data, function(dat) dat$value[1]))) %>% 
    unnest() 

df <- bind_rows(rep(list(data), 100000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(summarise_f(df), nest_f(df))
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
# summarise_f(df)  79.78891  89.65753 117.8480  93.56766  99.97694 277.3773   100
#      nest_f(df) 191.10597 208.07364 280.2466 225.65567 369.20202 524.5106   100
```

`Summarize` and then `join` is actually faster.

With a larger data set:

```
df <- bind_rows(rep(list(data), 1000000))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(summarise_f(df), nest_f(df))
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
# summarise_f(df)  819.5588  905.2136  993.4916  961.1797 1040.947 1480.391   100
#      nest_f(df) 1768.3060 1992.6753 2069.1454 2057.3091 2162.440 2501.715   100
```

Comment: I think you can avoid a bit more overhead in the `summarise` option too - `data %>% distinct(id,value) %>% mutate(cum_col=cumsum(value)) %>% select(-value) %>% inner_join(data, by="id")` for instance.

Comment: @Psidom @thelatemail
Thanks for your reply. The inner join means I need to save copy of data to be joined later. but this data is being produced as part of a pipe in dplyr. Changed few times in between.
`original_data %>% group_by (some columns) %>% mutate(add columns) %>% filter(conditions) %>% group_by(other columns) %>% mutate( calculate cumsum on one of other columns) %>% carry on with rest of operations`
`nest` although slow can be better option for avoiding the need to save data to join later on

Comment: @thelatemail Nice option. It's about same fast as `summarize`.

Comment: @Psidom - in your bigger `df`'s, you stlll only have 6 by-groups. I think if you make this much larger the `group_by` might cause a relative slowdown.

Comment: @thelatemail Agree. Just find it a bit harder to create a reproducible example.

Comment: @Kaur Write a summarize function as above and then chain it after your pipes could be one way to avoid saving intermediate data as well.

Comment: thats great! got few options now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is we create a dummy column (`cols`) which has only first `value` per group and rest are replaced by 0 and then we take `cumsum` over the entire column.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(cols = c(value[1], rep(0, n() -1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cum_col = cumsum(cols)) %>%
  select(-cols)


# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     id value other cum_col
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1    10     1      10
#2     1    10     2      10
#3     2    20     3      30
#4     2    20     4      30
#5     3    10     5      40
#6     4    30     6      70
#7     5    40     7     110
#8     6    50     8     160
```

Comment: Thanks, seems simple and clever way. But not sure about performance. Will see

Answer (score 3):

We could also do with `duplicated`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     mutate(cum_col = cumsum(value*!duplicated(id)))
#  id value other cum_col
#1  1    10     1      10
#2  1    10     2      10
#3  2    20     3      30
#4  2    20     4      30
#5  3    10     5      40
#6  4    30     6      70
#7  5    40     7     110
#8  6    50     8     160
```